# Is abc.ABC available in python 2.7.16?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abc

Based on https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html, it seems abstract classes are available starting in version 2.6 (the top says "New in version 2.6.")

However, I cannot
`from abc import ABC, abstractmethod` using python 2.7.16 as it produces the error:`ImportError: cannot import name ABC` but I can with python3+. So is `abc` not available for python 2.X?

Comment: Class `abc.ABC` is not available in 2.7 (as the linked documentation shows).

Comment: No, it implies that `abc.ABC` isn't available, which it isn't. It's just a convenience class to insert the metaclass, you can just use `abc.ABCMeta`. Of course, you really probably shouldn't be using python 2.7 to begin with

Comment: The module `abc` was added in 2.6, but this version of the module doesn't have the class `abc.ABC`. That was added in 3.4.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood the documentation. Unfortunately, the 2.7 is a unit test that I can't easily deprecate (it's part of a large codebase)